# RStudio, directory name is invalid

Tags: git, github, version-control, rstudio

I am trying to commit in RStudio, but am running into a 'Directory Name is Invalid' error. This happens every time I attempt to commit my changes. I have successfully committed before from this same PC to the same github repository I am attempting to now.

Initially, I cloned the repository through Rstudio by creating a new version control project and supplying my github URL.

The current wd doesn't have any funky characters and doesn't look much different than what I've used in the past:
("C:/Users/fname lname/Desktop/Columbia/assignment5")

I am running Windows 10 and Rstudio Version 0.99.903.

Screen Shots:

Attempting Commit in RStudio:

[image: Attempting Commit in RStudio]

Directory Name Invalid Error on Commit Pop Up:

[image: Directory Name Invalid Error on Commit Pop Up]

I found a couple other stackoverflow questions (21676188 and 39720104) that have similar issues, but not much in terms of suggestions.

Thanks for the help. If you need any more information, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is mainly caused by the working directory. Please check the project directory name, it should not contain any path, only the folder name is allowed.  You can check with below steps:

1. Check default working directory. In the console window of RStudio, input `getwd()`
2. Change the working directory to what you expected, use `setwd(“C:/Users/fname lname/Desktop/Columbia/assignment5”)` in console window
3. When you creating a new project, the **Project Direct Name** should only be `GitHub_repo_name/folder_name`, and do not contain C:/Users/fname lname/Desktop/Columbia/assignment5 in it.

**note:** detail changing WD you can refer [working directory and workspace](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200711843-Working-Directories-and-Workspaces)

Answer (score 0):

You may try to create the Project in a directory that doesn't have problematic characters.
I was having this same trouble, and when I created another project within a simpler directory name (not "~"'s or "ç" etc) the problem was solved.

Comment: The question already mentioned not using any funky characters.